# Performance challenge: Box operations (HackerRank) (C, Python)

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, c, programming-challenge

Recently I've been doing some challenges on HackerRank and came across this [one](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/box-operations/problem). First, I tried with Python, and then C. Both of my codes failed due to timeout restrictions.

It would be very helpful, if someone can tell me what can be improved in (one of) my codes (performance-wise).

Challenge description:

> Alice purchased an array of \$n\$ wooden boxes that she indexed from \$0\$ to \$n - 1\$.  On each box \$i\$, she writes an integer that we'll refer to as \$box_{i}\$.
>
> Alice wants you to perform \$q\$ operations on the array of boxes.  Each operation is in one of the following forms:
>
> (Note: For each type of operations, \$l \le i \le r\$)
>
> - `1 l r c`: Add \$c\$ to each \$box_{i}\$.  Note that \$c\$ can be negative.
> - `2 l r d`: Replace each \$box_{i}\$ with \$\left\lfloor\frac{box_{i}}{d}\right\rfloor\$.
> - `3 l r`: Print the minimum value of any \$box_{i}\$.
> - `4 l r`: Print the sum of all \$box_{i}\$.
>
> Recall that \$\lfloor x \rfloor\$ is the maximum integer \$y\$ such that \$ y \le x\$ (e.g., \$\lfloor -2.5\rfloor = -3\$ and \$\lfloor -7\rfloor = -7\$).
>
> Given \$n\$, the value of each \$box_{i}\$, and \$q\$ operations, can you perform all the operations efficiently?
>
> ### Input format
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the respective values of \$n\$ (the number of boxes) and \$q\$ (the number of operations).
>
> The second line contains \$n\$ space-separated integers describing the respective values of \$box_0, box_1, \dots, box_{n-1}\$ (i.e. the integers written on each box).
>
> Each of the \$q\$ subsequent lines describes an operation in one of the four formats described above.
>
> ### Constraints
>
> - \$1 \le n,q \le 10^5\$
> - \$-10^9 \le box_{i} \le 10^9\$
> - \$0 \le l \le r \le n - 1\$
> - \$-10^4 \le c \le 10^4\$
> - \$2 \le d \le 10^9\$
>
> ### Output Format
>
> For each operation of type \$3\$ or type \$4\$, print the answer on a new line.
>
> ### Sample Input 0
>
> ```
> 10 10
> -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
> 1 0 4 1
> 1 5 9 1
> 2 0 9 3
> 3 0 9
> 4 0 9
> 3 0 1
> 4 2 3
> 3 4 5
> 4 6 7
> 3 8 9
> ```
>
> ### Sample Output 0
>
> ```
> -2
> -2
> -2
> -2
> 0
> 1
> 1
> ```
>
> ### Explanation 0
>
> Initially, the array of boxes looks like this:
>
> `[ -5 ][ -4 ][ -3 ][ -2 ][ -1 ][ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ]`
>
> We perform the following sequence of operations on the array of boxes:
>
> 1. The first operation is `1 0 4 1`, so we add \$1\$ to each \$box_{i}\$ where \$0 \le i \le 4\$:
>
> `[ -4 ][ -3 ][ -2 ][ -1 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ]`
>
> 2. The second operation is `1 5 9 1`, so we add \$c = 1\$ to each \$box_i\$ where \$5 \le i \le 9\$.
>
> `[ -4 ][ -3 ][ -2 ][ -1 ][ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ][ 5 ]`
>
> 3. The third operation is `2 0 9 3`, so we divide each \$box_i\$ where \$0 \le i \le 9\$ by \$d = 3\$ and take the floor:
>
> `[ -2 ][ -1 ][ -1 ][ -1 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ][ 1 ][ 1 ]`
>
> 4. The fourth operation is `3 0 9`, so we print the minimum value of \$box_i\$ for \$0 \le i \le 9\$.
>    $$min(-2, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1) = -2$$
> 5. The fifth operation is `4 0 9`, so we print the sum of \$box_i\$ for \$0 \le i \le 9\$ which is the result of
>    $$ -2 + -1 + -1 + -1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = -2$$
>    ... and so on.

C code:

```
int minBox(int *box, int l, int r){
    int min=box[l];
    for(int i = l+1; i<=r; i++)
        if(box[i] < min)
            min = box[i];
    
    return min;
}

int sumBox(int *box, int l, int r){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i = l; i<=r; i++)
        sum += box[i];

    return sum;
}

void operateOnBox(int *op, int *box){
    switch(op[0]){
        case 3:
            printf("%d\n", minBox(box, op[1], op[2]));
            break;

        case 4:
            printf("%d\n", sumBox(box, op[1], op[2]));
            break;

        case 1:
            for(int i = op[1]; i <= op[2]; i++)
                box[i] += op[3];

            break;

        case 2:
            for(int i = op[1]; i <= op[2]; i++)
                box[i] = (int) floor(box[i]/((float)op[3]));

            break;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n, q, *box;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    box = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%d", box+i);

    for(int i = 0; i<q; i++){
        int op[4];
        scanf("%d %d %d", op, op+1, op+2);

        if(op[0] == 1 || op[0] == 2)
            scanf("%d", op+3);
        
        operateOnBox(op, box);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Python 3 code:

```
def operate(op, box):
    if op[0] == 3:
            print(min(box[op[1]:op[2]+1]))
    elif op[0] == 4:
            print(sum(box[op[1]:op[2]+1]))
    elif op[0] == 1:
            box[op[1]:op[2]+1] = map(lambda x: x+op[3], box[op[1]:op[2]+1])
    elif op[0] == 2:
            box[op[1]:op[2]+1] = map(lambda x: math.floor(x/op[3]), box[op[1]:op[2]+1])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    nq = input().split()

    n = int(nq[0])

    q = int(nq[1])

    box = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    for i in range(q):
        op = list(map(int, input().split()))
        operate(op, box)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Generally it's better to include text rather than an image because text is searchable and the image is not.  Also, the text tends to be smaller.

Comment: @Edward Thank you, I tried to paste a very brief description of it, but it contains mathematic formulas that do not render here. I'll keep it in my mind for next questions.

Comment: Please take a look at how other [tag:programming-challenge] questions have solved this.

Comment: I've edited the question for you to show how this can be done.  Please study it so you know how to do it yourself from here on.

Comment: @Edward I will, thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can time things yourself. How big of inputs can you handle? How much too slowly are you running? Pay especial attention to the given problem constraints.

Comment: I'm not sure how much experience you have with programming challenges, but if you're encountering timeouts, the problem is probably one that requires a clever algorithm, not slightly better code.